# Should POST array be dependency-injected or can it be just read from anywhere?

Tags: php, post, dependency-injection

Is there any reason to dependency-inject POST array into your controller?

For example, say I have this:

```
class Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->coverPageChoice = $_POST['coverpage'];
        $this->printNameplates = $_POST['print_nameplates'];
        $this->commentsOnSeparatePage = $_POST['comments_on_new_page'];
    }
}
```

Is there any benefit to injecting $_POST array into the constructor, something like this:

```
class Controller
{

    function __construct(array $input)
    {
        $this->coverPageChoice = $input['coverpage'];
        $this->printNameplates = $input['print_nameplates'];
        $this->commentsOnSeparatePage = $input['comments_on_new_page'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second method is more flexible and encapsulated (something fundamental to OOP). It will allow you to work with any array, instead of just $_POST. Say you want to run $_POST through a sanitization method first; you could have the output from that sanitization be the input for your constructor. But there's no  notable performance impact/gain, from either method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the second is better, for example to improve testability. And also to avoid dependency from outer world (yes, from PHP itself), so, it improves encapsulation.

Its even better to abstract $_POST out by some sort of class, to have consistent access to it, for example Request in Symfony: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation.html#request